# Être féru pour / de

Tags: sens, locutions

Bonjour,

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois I* :

> Moi aussi je **suis féru pour** l'air ! Je me vois ! Je vogue déjà !

Est-ce que *être féru pour* a le même sens de *être féru de* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La construction non-standard de cette phrase laisse la porte ouverte à toute interprétation. On peut cependant analyser *de l'air* comme une métonymie de *débarquement* en considérant ce qui vient d'être dit :

> *Y a du débarquement dans l’air !*

Le sens de la phrase serait alors, dans un autre registre :

> *Moi aussi, je suis enthousiasmé par cette perspective de débarquement qui se précise*.

L'absence de complément introduit par *de* à la suite de *féru* est très rare quand il a ce sens. *Pour* sert peut-être à faire comprendre au lecteur que ce qui suit n'est pas le complément auquel on s'attendrait.

*Féru* pouvait encore être utilisé à l'époque de Céline avec le sens originel de *blessé* que l'on retrouve dans d'autres langues romanes (es:*herido*, it:*ferito*, pt:*ferido*) mais ce sens est exclu ici.

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse ! La traduction anglaise donne :  "Me, too, I'm fated for the air! I can see it now! I'm already sailing!" Serait-il correct de comprendre "être féru pour" comme "être fait pour" ? Ou il s'agit d'une erreur de traduction ?

Comment: Comme je l'ai écrit, l'interprétation est assez libre, la traduction l'est donc aussi. On ne peut pas parler d'erreur de traduction, en particulier si *the air* se réfère aussi à la phrase précédente et son *dans l'air*.

Comment: D'accord, merci encore.

Comment: On peut parler d'erreur de traduction si on est traducteur littéraire vers l'anglais.

Comment: @Lambie Non, on peut parler d'erreur de traduction si on en a vu ou soupçonné une. Nul besoin d'être traducteur littéraire pour détecter certaines erreurs de traduction.

Comment: Oui, c'est ça. Ouf. Ce n'est pas la peine pour moi de discuter de ce métier avec toi si tu penses cela. Désolée.

Comment: @Lambie Donc, d'après toi, tous les traducteurs littéraires sont infaillibles et le commun des mortels n'a qu'à se taire. Pas la peine de discuter avec toi, effectivement.

Comment: That is not at all what I am saying. I **am saying** that literary translation is way beyond regular business, etc. translation. It takes a lot of training, writing talent, knowledge and experience. Why do you manipulate everything I say? Do you feel you have that? Be my guest then.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne manipule rien du tout. Tu as écrit *On peut parler d'erreur de traduction si on est traducteur littéraire vers l'anglais* et je te démontre que c'est faux. Si ce n'est pas ce que tu voulais dire, eh bien efface tous tes commentaires et cesse de m'en bombarder.

Comment: I tried to ask a question of ovide, but your interference made that impossible.

Comment: À _férir_ dans les plus vieux dictionnaires de l'Ac. on trouve des trucs comme _féru contre qqn_, indisposé contre... alors _disposé pour_ ?? Aussi, dans le sens d'_épris_, on donne le sens _passionné pour qqch_ au DHLF. Le sens et la syntaxe sont deux choses, mais peut-être qu'il y a un « prototype sous-jacent » qui influence hahaha, ouais, qui sait, ou le mot sert d'étiquette pour qqch. de plus courant parce qu'on est peu férus du sens ou des caractéristiques du verbe.

Answer (score 0):

À l'entrée de cet adjectif dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/f%C3%A9ru/1) on ne trouve pas la mention de la préposition « pour », seulement « de » est utilisé.

Si on fait une recherche sur les féquences respectives de ces prépositions après « féru » voici ce qu'on trouve.

[image]

[image]

Il faut quand même examiner les pages à partir desquelles le graphe de « pour » est construit. On s'aperçoit qu'un grand nombre de faux positif contribuent à ce graphe qui est déjà quasiment zéro sur toute la ligne du temps.

- Il est si féru pour Marie d'une « amoureuse litargie » qu'il se laisse crever un eil pour la voir

Dans l'exemple précédent la forme « normale » est « féru d'une amoureuse létargie pour Marie ».

> TLFi   P. ext. (emploi le plus cour.). (Être) féru de qqn ou de qqc.(Être) pris d'un vif intérêt **pour** quelqu'un ou quelque chose.

« Féru » peut donc s'employer avec deux prépositions, mais « de » reste la préposition de base.

Il semble que « pour » soit employé dans de rares cas, par exemple le suivant, qu'on trouve dans Céline.

- Moi aussi je suis féru pour l'air ! Je me vois ! Je vogue déjà !

Le sens est celui de « de ». Le dictionnaire de l'[Académie](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9F0556) ne mentionne pas « pour » non plus.

Comment: Je trouve à site:.fr être féru + pour lorsqu'il y a un verbe. Donc,  **est féru de X pour [verbe]**. Parfois, on laisse tomber le x. Par exemple, j'ai trouvé: Je me faisais une réflexion: faut quand même être féru pour faire du vélo à Rouen. – 
Lambie
 17 hours ago   Delete